# MFC : accessing CMainFrame's CImageList from ChildView

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to  add images to imagelist of toolbar, which is a member of  CMainFrame

```
startStopPicture.LoadBitmapW(IDB_STOP_PIC);
m_ToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().GetImageList()->Add(&startStopPicture, reinterpret_cast<CBitmap*>(NULL)); 

startStopPicture.DeleteObject();

startStopPicture.LoadBitmapW(IDB_START_PIC);
m_ToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().GetImageList()->Add(&startStopPicture, reinterpret_cast<CBitmap*>(NULL));
```

then I need to access this imagelist from childview. I'm trying do to it like this

```
CMainFrame* mainFrame = dynamic_cast<CMainFrame*>(GetParentFrame());

CImageList* imList = mainFrame->m_ToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().GetImageList();
```

But those images I added in the mainframe's method are absent now. How to solve this promlem?

Comment: When you need the image list in the child, create one in this class. It is bad design to access such members accross classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your [`CBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35.aspx) `startStopPicture` is a local variable, since you neither mentioned otherwise or preceded the variable name with any class-like-identifier. Afterwards you try to store via [`CImageList::Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z9sc5dx.aspx) *a local variable by reference*.

What you have to do is either allocating the [`CBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35.aspx) - `new CBitmap` or add the `startStopPicture` variable to your class as a member.

If you choose to allocate the variable and do not have to keep track of the [`CBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35.aspx), you could use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CBitmap> >` as class-member.

If you store a local variable [`CBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35.aspx) in a [`CImageList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xc4z2c7.aspx), the image will not display.

Example:

```
//class declaration
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CBitmap> > m_vLoadedBitmaps;
};

void CMyCtrl::SetBitmaps(CImageList &imgList)
{
    CBitmap *bmpDelete = new CBitmap();
    bmpDelete->LoadBitmapW(IDB_DELETE);
    m_vLoadedBitmaps.push_back(std::unique_ptr<CBitmap>(bmpDelete));

    imgList.Add(bmpDelete, static_cast<CBitmap*>(NULL));
}
```

Also I would recommend loading the images in the owner class of the variable. If needed, there's still [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Exactly what i need :) thanx!